# Page tab increasing height when necessary, but not decreasing

Tags: tabs, height, facebook-page

In my facebook page tab app I have a couple of different pages that are of different height. As title says, the page pushes the height up when necessary, but the window height doesn't return to shortest possible when I go back to a page that doesn't require much height. This is how it looks:

http://www.facebook.com/EasterIslandTraveling/app_167418876720611

The "Basics" page is the tall page I'm referring to.

After FB.init i use FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); which should do the trick, right? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using FB.init(), first fb js library must be initialized. So you have to include FB.init() function inside window.fbAsyncInit event like as follows:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()  {
            FB.init({ appId: 'FB APP ID', 
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });

            FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 700 });
        }
```

You can think as you are writing a javascript inside document ready event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* Js Code */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the height by using this given below code

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function()  {
            FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR APP ID', 
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });

            FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 600 }); // You can set height here..
        }
</script>
```

This is working perfectly for me. Let me know if it doesn't work!!